# Failed to install gnome-tweak-tool in ubuntu 21.04 just installed

Tags: dependencies, 21.04, gnome-tweaks

After installing ubuntu 21.04 and update all packages I tried to install gnome-tweak-tool and I get a error because of dependencies.

```
smaceda@molexps15:~$ sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
[sudo] password for smaceda:  
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done 
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  gnome-shell-extension-prefs : 
Depends: gnome-shell (=3.38.4-1ubuntu3~21.04.1) but 3.38.4-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 3.38.4-1ubuntu3~21.04.1) but 3.38.4-1ubuntu2 is to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. 
smaceda@molexps15:~$
```

How can I resolve it? I'm new to ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: To be sure please add output of `apt-cache policy gnome-tweak-tool gnome-shell-extension-prefs gnome-shell gnome-shell-common` to the question. You are probably miss *hirsute-updates* pocket.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

I updated packages with matching versions and it seems to work:

```
sudo apt -f install gnome-shell=3.38.4-1ubuntu3~21.04.1 gnome-shell-common=3.38.4-1ubuntu3~21.04.1
```